# HAProxy nbsrv seems to give wrong value

Tags: haproxy

I'm using `nbsrv` in an ACL rule to determine if the request should be permitted(1).

Example configuration:

```
defaults 
  mode http 

frontend front_www
  listen 0.0.0.0:80 

  acl acl_backend_down nbsrv(back_www) lt 1 

  http-request deny if acl_backend_down 

  default_backend back_www

backend back_wwww

  server s1 1.2.3.1:80 check 
  server s2 1.2.3.2:80 check 
  server haproxy-dc2 1.3.4.1:80 check backup
```

With this configuration, I would expect that when s1 and s2 are down, that nbserv would be 0 and thus return a HTTP 403.

Unfortunately it doesn't send 403 until I take down the backup server (haproxy-dc2).

If I change the ACL rule to less than two (i.e):

```
acl acl_backend_down nbsrv(back_www) lt 2
```

Then it operates as I would perhaps expect: when there's only one primary available in the backend, it sends 403.

I thought perhaps there was something odd with the less than operator, so changed it to `eq 0`, but this doesn't work either.

Is there some way to force nbsrv to work like I'm expecting, or some other way of detecting that all the primaries for the backend are down?

(1) This ACL is part of a larger set of rules, I'm simplifying it down to the smallest reproducable example. If you have an alternative solution which would let me detect if we're using a backup server, then please let me know. The tl;dr of the larger picture is to permit two haproxy instances to fail over to each other, but prevent infinite loops (eg if dc01's backend is down, the response to dc02's healthcheck of dc01 should be a 403/down)

e:

To add some context to my comments on @gf_'s solution below... our production environment is rather complex. There's multiple backups+multiple DCs, and each instance has many backends (multiple applications, plus content switching)

For monitoring - theres internal HAProxy health-checks between instances, but also external monitoring via collectd+zabbix which will send us alerts if all of a backend's servers are unhealthy. Knowing that there's no backups available means we can bump the priority of the alert.

So, this is why I simplified the example down just showing `nbsrv(back_www) lt 1` as the thing I was trying to fix.

At the moment I'm leaning towards going with lt 2 and assuming that if there's only the one box up, we don't want the other LBs to fail over here anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the question, this is what ServerFault is made for!

Comment: I would like to get this solved, but my impression is that we need a more direct contact for this. Will, if you're interested, could you send me a mail (in my profile)? In case you've solved this already, could you update your question, or, better, post an answer?

Comment: Any updates? Still curious... :)

Comment: @gf_ Thanks, I've gone with nbsrv lt 2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if the following will work for you, and can't test right now, but maybe it's helpful, still:

`HAProxy config of dc01`:

```
defaults 
  mode http 

frontend front_www
  listen 0.0.0.0:80 

  acl acl_backend_down nbsrv(back_www) lt 1 

  monitor-uri /health
  monitor fail if acl_backend_down

  use_backend dc02 if acl_backend_down
  default_backend back_www

backend back_wwww
  server s1 1.2.3.1:80 check 
  server s2 1.2.3.2:80 check

backend dc02
  server haproxy-dc2 1.3.4.1:80 check
```

Leverage the [monitor-uri](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#monitor-uri) and [monitor fail](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4.2-monitor%20fail) directives and check `/health` from `dc02` (and vice versa). `/health` should report `HTTP 200` if at least one backend is alive and healthy, otherwise `HTTP 503`.

Comment: So the underlying solution of 'split the backups to their own backend' does seem to fix the ``lt 1`` issue - I don't need to use monitor-uri and monitor fail. The weird thing is that ``lt 2`` still does the right thing if I have multiple backups on the main backend.

Comment: One thing I should mention is that the disadvantage to this method of splitting the backups out, is that it complicates the checking of number of servers up vs number of backups up in external monitoring scripts (zabbix).

Comment: @WillHughes 1.) I understood you've got two HAProxy instances, and each (or an external monitoring system) should check  the other for health, that's why I've introduced the `monitor ...` directives. 2.) How many backends are there in your (production) config? Isn't there just one (main) backup server, the other HAproxy instance? 3.) Could you try to make these limitations more clear in your question?

Comment: I've added more detail in my question, since it won't fit here.  The tl;dr is that the environment is a lot more complex, so splitting out backups makes ``lt 1`` work, but isn't ideal.